# Azure API Management: What is a good practise to handle different environments?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using Azure API Management to document and test several webservices and endpoints in different environments like dev, test and prod. Currently, I separate different enviroments via different APIs. Then I tag them in order have a better overview of the APIs. I am wondering if there is a better solution to deal with environments in Azure API Management? Because with this solution I have several similar requests...

(I am thinking about something like "Environments" in Postman.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find below some of the options you could try:

**Option #1:**
As you rightly mentioned, using tags for Dev, Production and Staging environments can help. You can then leverage the Filter by Tags or Group by Tags options while working on a particular environment.[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PYjT.png)

**Option #2:**
Other alternative is to leverage the [APIM versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-versions) feature **to some extent** though *it is not meant for your exact requirement*. This allows the creation of different API versions that can be moved between environments like Dev / Prod. Each version can be customized with its own settings and policies, offering flexibility to change each version independently.

**Option #3:**
You could try using tools such as [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/devops-api-development-templates) or other CI/CD tools to transfer API management resources between environments. With this approach, APIs and policies can be managed in code, and pipelines can be used to deploy them to different environments.

**Option #4:**
Additionally, [named values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties?tabs=azure-portal) can be employed to store environment-specific information like API keys and connection strings, thereby eliminating the need to recreate configurations for different APIs and versions.

Depending on your requirement, you may explore these options and choose the most suitable one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will go through them and try to find the best solution for me. I am still surprised that APIM does not offer a good solution....